# Words for Sounds in Screenplay

Tags: scriptwriting, screenwriting

Is there any list of words use in screenplay?  Like below. What word I can use to describe the sound of metal gate and a sound of a tower built in metal?
THUD - body fall sound
BANG - some blast sound, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *screech, clang, clank, groan*.

• *[screech](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screech#Noun)*, “A high-pitched strident or piercing sound, such as that between a moving object and any surface.”
• *[clang](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clang#Noun)*, “A loud, ringing sound, like that made by free-hanging metal objects striking each other.”
• *[clank](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clank#Noun)*, “A loud, hard sound of metal hitting metal.  Usage note: Clank usually expresses a duller or less resounding sound than clang, and a deeper and stronger sound than clink.”
• *[groan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/groan#Noun)*, for which wiktionary only shows senses like “A low, mournful sound uttered in pain or grief”, but the word sometimes is used to characterize rending, wrenching, ratcheting, or tearing noises as metal is stressed not just beyond its yield point but beyond its ultimate strength.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply describe the FX you want.

*Footsteps on gravel, rusty metal gate opening, reverberating gunshot, scream of pain* is far more useful in a screenplay than *Crunch, Creak, Kapowee, Aaaagh*. Unless of course you are writing a comic book.

Comment: This has the added benefit of telling a sound designer what sound to reproduce, rather than having then guess what *kaboooom* means.